# Binary Search Tree Small Count Exercise

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a method that does the following:
Given a BST, write a recursive function BSTsmallcount that, given a key value, returns the number of nodes having values less than the key. Your function should visit as few nodes in the BST as possible.

This is what I have:

```
public int BSTsmallcount(BinNode root, int key)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (root.right < key)
    {
        count += BSTsmallcount(root.left, key);
    }
    if (root.left < key)
    {
        count += BSTsmallcount(root.right, key);
    }
    return count;

}
```

However this is incorrect because you can't use binary operators. How would I complete this problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify that restriction on binary operators?  Are you really supposed to do this without arithmetic, boolean, or construction operators?  It seems weird to attack this without even `<`.

Comment: I'm not sure, it gives me this error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'

Comment: What gives you that error? The compiler? That error is not saying you may not use binary operator '<'. It is saying you are using '<' incorrectly, giving it bad parameters. That is probably because root.right and root.left are of type BinNode, rather than the expected type int.

Comment: Yeah it's the compiler on the coding practice website I'm using. I guess my mistake is that I need to access the node's VALUE, but node.getElement and node.value are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Ya so you cannot just compare a address with a value, I think this is what you need

```
public int BSTsmallcount(BinNode root, int key)
{
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    if (root.left.value < key)
        return 1 + BSTsmallcount(root.left, key);
    else
        return BSTsmallcount(root.left, key);
    if (root.right.value < key)
        return 1 + BSTsmallcount(root.right, key);
    else
        return BSTsmallcount(root.right, key);
}
```

There must be an attribute in class BinNode that stores the value of that node.

Comment: This hits all the nodes. The question want to hit the minimum number.

Comment: It gave me this error: cannot find symbol: variable value. I've even tried the compareTo method but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Harshi can you paste the structure of BinNode class here

Comment: By value, I meant any value attribute for the BinNode class, it could be either val or Value or value, etc.. what not, it could be anything that you specify for that class

Comment: @zenwraight I'm not sure if I can do that, this is on a coding practice website.

Comment: @Harshi can you send my the link to that problem, paste it here

Comment: @zenwraight, this will break when either root.left or root.right are null.

Comment: is there a way to access the node's value other than getElement or value? because that's my issue i think

Comment: We don't know; you have posted or properly referenced the **BinNode** class.

Comment: @Harshi and Prune, did this code work for you guys ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public int BSTsmallcount(BinNode root, int key){
if(root == null) return 0;
if (root.value() < key)
    return 1 + BSTsmallcount(root.left(), key);
else
    return BSTsmallcount(root.left(), key);
}
```

Corrections:
1. it should be null instead of NULL
2. A proper recursive method would only check its **own** base case. Therefore, there is no need to check for the child's value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public int BSTsmallcount(BinNode root, int key)
{
    if(root == null) return 0;

    if (root.value()<key){
        return 1+ BSTsmallcount(root.left(),key)+BSTsmallcount(root.right(),key);
    
    }

    else{
        return BSTsmallcount(root.left(),key);
    }

}
```